# Redirect dynamic language slug

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect the URLs of my old page to the new.
There the logic of the language has changed.

Old:

http://example.com/cms/de/help-contact/glossar/cookie

New:

http://example.com/cms/de/cookie

I have several languages with same slug, just difference in language slug.

So i want to try to redirect the urls dynamically.
When i do it directly, it works like:

```
Redirect 301 /cms/de/help-contact/glossar/cookie /cms/de/cookie
```

I googled and found some posts but nothing that helped me really.
So i already tried:

```
Redirect 301 /cms/([^/]+)/help-contact/glossar/cookie /cms/$1/cookie
```

Or:

```
Redirect 301 /cms/([a-z]{2})/help-contact/glossar/cookie /cms/$1/cookie
```

But it didn't wokred.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirect directive doesnt support regex. What you are looking for is **RedirectMatch** .

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/cms/([^/]+)/help-contant/glossar/(.+)$ /cms/$1/$2/
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I tested here: http://htaccess.mwl.be/ but don't seems to work

Comment: What uri are you testing this against? On my server it works fine if i go to **/cms/de/help-contant/glossar/foobar** it redirect the uri to **/cms/de/foobar**